# one dimensional integration- flux

Tags: calculus, surface-integrals

How can I calculate one dimensional integration from three dimensional one?

**Problem:**
Calculate flux of the vector field $F=(-y, x, z^2)$ through the tetraeder $T(ABCD)$ with the corner points $A= (\frac{3}{2}, 0, 0), B= (0, \frac{\sqrt 3}{2},0), C = (0, -\frac{\sqrt 3}{2},0), D =  (\frac{1}{2},0 , \sqrt 2)$ by one dimensional integrtion.

I calculated div, where $divF = 2z$

I can see from the points distribution that $z\in  [0,\sqrt 2] $ And according to theorem of Gauss I should apply this formula.

$\iiint_TdivFdv$

How can I seperate the integrals to get one dimensional?

Comment: My interpretation is that they want you to set the volume integral up as a $z$-integral. (Note that the slices of the tetrahedron perpendicular to the $z$-axis are all similar triangles.)

Comment: @TedShifrin My problem is that I don't know how to correctly define the upper and lower limits of definite integrals for x, y and z?